# do nested loops in Casperjs

Tags: casperjs, nested-loops

I am new in Casperjs and I would like do dinamic testing depending on external data sources. But, I am experiencing some problems with the loops.

This is my code:

```
var url = ['http://google.com/','http://www.as.com'];

casper.test.begin('PruebaLoop', function (test) {

casper.start('about:blank',function() {

}); 

casper.then(function() {
        casper.viewport(1024, 768);
        //casper.echo(casper.getTitle());
});

console.log('url.length: ' + url.length)

for (i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
        casper.thenOpen(url[i], function() { // open that link
        console.log('i: '+i);
        });

        casper.wait(5000, function() {
                this.echo("I've waited for a 5 seconds.");
        });

        casper.then(function() {
                    casper.capture('url'+i+'.png');
        }); 
}

casper.run(function() {
casper.echo('Test completado');
casper.test.done();
});

 });
```

From debugging, I always get 2 as the result. I don't know why. Could you please offer me some help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CasperJS: Iterating through URL's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360993/casperjs-iterating-through-urls)

Answer (score 1):

> my solution is:

```
var urls = ['http://www.elpais.es','http://www.as.com'];

casper.test.begin('PruebaLoop', function (test) {


                    casper.start('auto:blank',function() {
                    console.log("-----------------------------------");
                    console.log("estoy en start ");
                }); 

                    casper.then(function() {
                        casper.viewport(1024, 768);
                        console.log("estoy en wiewport");
                        console.log("urls.length = " + urls.length);
                        console.log("-----------------------------------");

                });

          for(i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

            (function(index) {
              var url = urls[index]

                casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
                    console.log('index tiene el valor: '+ index);
                    console.log('i tiene el valor: '+ i);
                });

                casper.then(function() {
                    this.wait(5000);
                    console.log("estoy en wait: "+ index);
                });

                casper.then(function() {
                    this.wait(5000);
                    casper.capture("pagina"+index+".png");
                    console.log("estoy en capture: " + index);
                    console.log("-----------------------------------");
                }); 

              })(i);
        }

    casper.run(function() {
        casper.echo('Test completado');
        casper.test.done();
    });

 });
```

> it works.