# How to check http status code in Casperjs?

Tags: casperjs

I want to check http status code using casperjs. I have 500 links and I want to check status code of each link.

Comment: We're not here to write code for you. Read the documentation and look for examples how to iterate over a list of URLs in CasperJS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CasperJS: Iterating through URL's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360993/casperjs-iterating-through-urls)

Comment: I have array with  500 links  I am iterate using Casper.eachthen and checking status code for  each link using thenOpen but after executing several links its became idle no further status code display, don't  understand why its remain idle?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this suggestion can fit you!
In the very site of the official documentation there are some code examples for you to implement.

In your case, you can achieve this status control of 3 different ways:
Using `resource.received`,`resource.requested` or individually in each status control routine `http.status.[code]`.

To work with `resource.received`, you can see an example in [this link](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-resource-received).

To work with `resource.requested`, you can see an example in [this link](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-resource-requested).

To work with `http.status.[code]`, you can see an example in [this link](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#http-status-code).

I hope you can help you! See you later...

Comment: Let us assume that we have 500 links. If any link is taking more than a certain amount of time to respond, we wish to skip to the next in the list.Can we set the timeout in page.resource.requested event.

     casper.then(function() {
     casper.on('page.resource.requested',function(requestData,request)    {
     /* Can I set Timeout Here*/
 });
casper.eachThen(links, function(response) {
      var finalURL = response.data;
      casper.thenOpen(finalURL, function(response) {
       console.log(finalURL);
        console.log("Status:::::",response.status)
      })

 })
Please help me?

Comment: Do you want to treat your timeout BY REQUEST or FOR PAGE? By default, CasperJS timeout functions are for a complete requisition (page) ... but it is possible, within the resource.requested block, you put a waitFor function or use waitForResource.

http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforresource

Comment: as I have  the array of links and checking status code of each link but in between the  execution is ideal, I want to set a timeout so that if execution is ideal then the next link in the array will process  for checking the status code

Comment: I want to set timeout by request