# CasperJS looping through each URL

Tags: javascript

This question is [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360993/casperjs-iterating-through-urls) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384963/casperjs-loop-or-iterate-through-multiple-web-pages) [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421307/how-to-tell-casperjs-to-loop-through-a-series-of-pages), but the problem I had was more basic.

This is my code:

```
var links = [];
var casper = require('casper').create();

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('div#mw-content-text table.wikitable tbody tr td i b a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return 'https://en.wikipedia.org' + e.getAttribute('href');
    });
}

casper.start('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Bowie_discography');

casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results for the 'casperjs' search
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});

casper.each(links, function (self, link) {
    self.thenOpen(fullURL, function () {
        this.echo(this.getTitle() + " - " + link);
    });
});

casper.run();
```

I know that `links` get created as it is copied from the [Quickstart](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#now-let-s-scrape-google), but I then modified it to open all the links that were found.

What I'm getting is that nothing is echo'd instead of outputting the each title which is what I expect. This is how I'm calling the file:

```
~ $ casperjs casper-google-disco.js
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fix was very easy in the end, but took me ages to find it as there were no errors and no-one else seemed to have hit this.

The problem is that the `links` variable doesn't get set before the `each` is called. Putting the `each` inside the `then` function solves my problem.

The [`each.js` example](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/blob/master/samples/each.js) in the CasperJS samples was helpful for confirming that you can loop through an array without any need for [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360993/casperjs-iterating-through-urls#comment37669655_24360993).

```
var links = [];
var casper = require('casper').create();

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('div#mw-content-text table.wikitable tbody tr td i b a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return 'https://en.wikipedia.org' + e.getAttribute('href');
    });
}

casper.start('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Bowie_discography');

casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results for the 'casperjs' search
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);

    casper.each(links, function (self, link) {
        self.thenOpen(link, function () {
            this.echo(this.getTitle() + " - " + link);
        });
    });
});


casper.run();
```